# Setting Cookies in browser for video autoplay

Tags: javascript, video, cookies, embed, movie

How would I set cookies such that a video only plays automatically on the first visit only, afterwards if they want to watch it, it must be played manually?

Answer (score 1):

The general idea would be:

1. on page load retrieve cookie information
2. if no cookie, or its set to false, play the movie
3. set cookie to true

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I used on a project:

```
if (document.cookie.length == 0 || document.cookie.indexOf("MYCOOKIENAME=") == -1) {
  // I set the path to / so once they'd seen it once on the site they wouldn't
  // see it on other pages.
  document.cookie = "MYCOOKIENAME=true; path=/;";

  // START VIDEO PLAYING HERE.
}
```

I didn't really want the overhead of adding a cookie library.

Plugging my code into Oliver Moran's HTML gives you:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" id="videoframe" width="480" height="390" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script language="javascript">
var link = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/he5fpsmH_2g";

if (document.cookie.length == 0 || document.cookie.indexOf("MYCOOKIENAME=") == -1) {
  // I set the path to / so once they'd seen it once on the site they wouldn't
  // see it on other pages.
  document.cookie = "MYCOOKIENAME=true; path=/;";

  link += "?autoplay=1"; // append an autoplay tag to the video URL
}

document.getElementById("videoframe").src =  link; // set the iframe src

</script>
```

Comment: I got an email asking how to make the cookie last longer than the session. To do that you need to tell the browser when the cookie expires, if no date is specified it'll treat the cookie as a session cookie meaning that once you close the browser the cookie's value is lost. You can append something like "; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2060 05:00:00 GMT;" onto the string we assign to document.cookie and it should keep it around for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

Per Justin808's answer, the general idea would be like this:

```
if (!cookieIsSet()) {
  setCookie();
  playMovie();
}
```

See the W3Schools site for an example use of cookies similar to what you want to achieve: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

If you are embedding a YouTube video you could do it like this:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" id="videoframe" width="480" height="390" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script language="javascript">

var link = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/he5fpsmH_2g";

if (!cookieIsSet()) {
  setCookie();
  link += "?autoplay=1"; // append an autoplay tag to the video URL
}

document.getElementById("videoframe").src =  link; // set the iframe src

</script>
```

Obviously, you would have to define your own `cookieIsSet()` and `setCookie()` functions. See the W3School's site for examples how.