# How to create html5 audio and toggle it depending on a cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, html5-audio

I have the following code, that tries to play an audio file, and then on pressing the link, you can toggle it on or off (it saves a cookie to save your preference). For some reason the audio does play, but clicking the link does nothing. Ideas? I'm thinking there's something obvious in the cookie part I missed, because this is the first time I'm touching cookies with javascript.

```
<p><a href="" onclick="Javascript:toggle()">Ääni päälle/pois</a><br />
<script>
window.onload=function(){
var pre='';
var ele=document.getElementById('test');
ele.play();
//when the song ends start a new one
ele.onended=function(){
  //if you are done with all the songs loop back to the beginning.
  //Or you could add some code to load more songs from the server
  ele.play();
}

}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

function toggle() {
    if(!readCookie(sound)){
        createCookie(sound,false,100);
    }
    else if(readCookie(sound)==false){
        createCookie(sound,true,100);
        ele.play();
    }
    else if(readCookie(sound)==true){
        createCookie(sound,false,100);
        ele.pause();
    }
}

</script></p>
```

Comment: Cookies is always strings, so first toggle() creates cookie with text "false", next - reads "false", compare it with boolean `false` (which will not be equals) and... do nothing because this is behavior not described in toggle(). To fix this, you need compare readCookie() result with strings "false" and "true". Side note: save result to var so you won't need to run readCookie 3 times.

Comment: Also, I don't see where `sound` is defined, it's probably should be string `"sound"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Cookies in browser for video autoplay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480444/setting-cookies-in-browser-for-video-autoplay)