# How to block ads for youtube videos playing in youtube player api?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am using Youtube player to play youtube videos. I am getting ads continuesly,which I need to skip after 5sec. I just wants to block these while playing the youtube videos.
 Did I have any chance to do this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

From [Embed YouTube Video with No Ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981310/embed-youtube-video-with-no-ads), there's a link to [Ads on Embedded Videos](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en):

> **Enable or disable ads on embedded videos**
>
> You will automatically be opted into showing ads on embedded videos if
>   you've associated your YouTube and AdSense accounts and have enabled
>   your videos for embedding.
>
> If you don't want to show overlay ads on your embedded videos, you can
>   opt your videos out of showing overlay ads, though this will also
>   disable overlay ads on your videos on YouTube.com. You may also
>   disable your videos for embedding.

see also: [How can I disable the advertisements shown before Youtube videos?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18453/how-can-i-disable-the-advertisements-shown-before-youtube-videos)

edited for ideas on using code, see: [Setting Cookies in browser for video autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480444/setting-cookies-in-browser-for-video-autoplay/5480702#5480702) and then try to use the code at [How to Disable All YouTube Ads with a Simple Browser Hack – Guide](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Disable-All-YouTube-Ads-with-a-Simple-Browser-Hack-Guide-377198.shtml)

Comment: can I do it from coding?

Comment: I want to do something in Android to stop ads in Youtube player,can you help in that way?